# What does dimensionless quantity 'number of $g$' mean?

Tags: gravity, terminology, acceleration, notation

I am doing data analysis in which I found a quantity named "no. of $g$".
I don't know what it means or what is its usage.

Look at the image below.

[image]

I want to know the meaning and usage of "no. of $g$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The acceleration due to gravity near the Earth's surface is often denoted $g$.
Given any other acceleration $a$, we call $a/g$ the "number of $g$'s" because it is just the number you multiply by $g$ to get $a$.
For example, if we say an acceleration $a$ is "2 $g$'s" then that means
$$a = 2 \times g = 2 \times 9.8 \text{m}/\text{s}^2 = 19.6 \text{m}/\text{s}^2 \, .$$